# Can a Christian be called but not chosen?

Tags: soteriology, christians, elect

The concept of many are called but few are chosen is very alive in the Bible where Jesus says that no one can come to him unless God allows it.

**Mathew 22:14**

> Indeed many are called but few are chosen

Also the verse that states that a man cannot receive anything unless it is granted to him from heaven including eternal life

**John 3:27**

> A person cannot receive even one thing unless it is given him from heaven.

This two verses show that even for Christians they cannot come to God unless God already called them and no matter what they do, if God hasn't called them they won't be saved. So is there any circumstance where a believer can have the status of being called but not chosen ?

Comment: One needs to very carefully define (from scripture) the precise concepts of 'Christian', 'believer', 'called' and'chosen', in order to arrive at a satisfactory and correct conclusion. I am sure there will be much conjecture and many traditional views on this.

Comment: @NigelJ, Judas was called but not chosen ad that explains his end. He was a apostle who was called but not chosen

Comment: Can you substantiate that Judas was _personally_ called : and not as one, among many, receiving a general exhortation ? Compare Nathaniel under the fig tree or Andrew and John receiving a personal invitation or Peter being called as an individual. Many are called, given encouragement, exhorted to repent, called to depart from iniquity. But few are chosen.

Comment: Your question hinges on whom you define as 'Christian' and 'believer'. Multitudes never find where the strait gate is. And many seek to enter in to the strait gate. But few are able. Judas was 'chosen' among eleven others. But on what basis was he 'chosen' - given the opportunity to be the traitor he always was ?

Comment: @NigelJ, so if many desire to enter through the straight, does the many include Christians because there is no one who calls himself a Christian without being a believer

Comment: The gate opens to a way which leads to life. Some are unable to get through the gate (carrying too much ?). One can label these people in any way one chooses. The fact of their existence is that they were unable to proceed to the way of life. They may be 'religious' and they may identify as 'Christian'. It depends _what_ they believe. Jesus said take heed _what_ ye hear and take heed _how_ ye hear. It is important to hear the correct doctrine and it is important to receive that doctrine into a 'good heart' and to respond with true faith. It is necessary to _respond aright_ to _real truth_.

Comment: @NigelJ, I guess that's why many of the _elect_ will for the coming deception because they were called but not chosen

Comment: The elect  will not be deceived, because they were chosen. And they overcome.

Comment: Depends on your interpretation of called and chosen but Isreal were the elect yet many were reprobate and abandoned the God of their fathers.

Comment: @Joseph - "Elect" means "chosen", it is the same meaning.  A person or nation may be outwardly chosen for a purpose but not spiritually chosen.  "Elect" in the New Testament means spiritually, inwardly, chosen for salvation.

Comment: where are you getting the "inward"/ "outward" distinction from?

Comment: @Joseph , what do you mean by inward/outward distinction ?

Comment: what Andrew said in the previous comment sorry

Comment: @Joseph, Thanks for clarifying you were replying to Andrew, in future when replying to a comment made by a unique user kindly start with @ followed by the username of the user to avoid a repeat of this because I thought it was directed towards me

Comment: @Joseph - if you don't address with @ i am not going to see your comment, unless I happen to wade through the comments and find it by chance.  Israel was chosen outwardly to be a figure/type of God's people outwardly.  But only those who are born again of the Spirit of God are truly God's people ( inwardly). Only those inwardly born again are God's people, together with the elect who have not yet experienced the new birth but will do because they have been chosen by God.

Comment: Matthew 7:21-26 read all parables

Answer (score 4):

Every true Christian has been called and chosen. (But the example of Judas Iscariot is a warning to us all to make our calling and election sure.)

There is a general call and an effectual call.

Many hear the *general* call. Whenever a person hears the Gospel with its call to repent and believe on the Son of God, they receive the general call. But many do not respond with repentance and faith for "many are called but few are chosen", Matthew 22:14.

Then there is the *effectual* call as described by Paul in Romans:

> And we know all things work together for good, to them that love God, to them that are the called according to his purpose. For whom he did foreknow, them he also did predestinate to be conformed to the image of his Son, that he might be the firstborn among many brethren.
> Moreover whom he did predestinate, them he also called; and whom he called, them he also justified; and whom he justified, them he also glorified. Romans 8:28-30.

The above passage is a golden chain of salvation which cannot be broken. It describes the effectual calling of the few who have been chosen: these are the elect who at some point in life will truly believe, repent, and thus become a true Christian. All true Christians have been effectually called to salvation.

Judas Iscariot was called to be an apostle but was not effectually called to be saved.

*Postscript*

As Jesus said:
"No one can come to me unless the Father who sent me draws him, and I will raise him up at the last day", John 6:44.

*Post postscript*

The OP writes:

> These two verses show that even for Christians they cannot come to God unless God already called them and, no matter what they do, if God hasn't called them they won't be saved. So is there any circumstance where a believer can have the status of being called but not chosen?

It is really hard to know what is intended here.  There are two groups:

1. There is someone who says he is a Christian but is not, he has not put all his trust in Christ alone; Let me call him a "False Brother".  I do not mean he is intentionally false: he might not know he is not a true believer; and
2. There are those who are truly Christian. Let me call them True Believers.

If in your closing paragraph you mean a True Believer:

A Christian (True Believer) is, by definition, someone who has already come to God.

A Christian is, by definition, already saved.

And a True Believer has come to God and been saved because God has already effectually called them.

If the OP means by "Christian" a False Brother then for as long as others think he is a true Christian he will have the status amongst other believers of having been effectually called but only God knows if he has been chosen.. he may yet be chosen but not yet effectually called.

**Is it that "They cannot come to God.. no matter what they do"?**

It is not a good way of speaking.  It is not that they cannot come to God, it is really that they **will not** come to God.  They have no desire to come to God.

And it is not "no matter what they do".  Rather it is that, if they do anything at all, it is not with the sincere desire to find God.  They have no desire for God.

If anyone, anywhere pursues the means of faith alone in Christ alone, if anyone pursues the means that God has given in Scripture and calls upon the name of God for help and grace and pardon they will be saved.  If *anyone* seeks, and keeps on seeking, they will find.  Our Lord Jesus has promised it.

Though a man may know that he is saved and (if he believes the doctrine of effectual calling and election and predestination) though he may know because he knows he is saved thus he may know he was chosen by God in Christ before the foundation of the world; **no man should believe he is not elect such that he makes no effort to find Christ and salvation in Christ**.  No one knows that they are not elect.  So *all* should pursue the means of salvation.  All should believe the words of Jesus Christ "If anyone believes on me... out of his belly shall flow rivers of living water." John 7:38.  He should read the scriptures, especially the gospels of Matthew, Mark, Luke, and John.

If anyone knows he is not yet saved, and finds an awakening desire to be saved, he should pursue the means of salvation, faith alone in a crucified Saviour who died that our sins might be forgiven by believing on the only Saviour:

Knock and the door shall be opened to you (Matthew 7:7). It is the promise of the only begotten Son of God.

Look unto me and be you saved all the ends of the earth, for I am God and there is no other. Isaiah 45:22

And just as Moses lifted up the serpent in the wilderness even so must the Son of Man be lifted up that whoever believes in him should not perish, but have eternal life. (Numbers 21:4-9, John 3:14-15)

Come unto me all you that are heavy laden and I will give you rest. Matthew 11:28

To the one who does not work, but believes on him who justifies the ungodly, his faith is credited to him as righteousness. Romans 4:5.

No one should see the doctrine of election as a wall that keeps them out, but once a sinner is saved let him see the doctrine of election be a wall that helps to keep them in. When Christ was dying he was not dying for all the sinners in general, he was dying for his own sheep who he knew by name.

He lovèd me and gave Himself for me,
Amazing love, amazing sacrifice!

I'll take my harp down from the willow tree,
And bid its note in praise of Jesus rise.

He lovèd me and gave Himself for me,
And surely I myself to Him will give;

None Jesus will I ever love like Thee,
And to Thy glory only will I live.

Comment: +1 upvote. So someone like Paul was chosen even though he was responsible for the death of many saints?

Comment: Exactly right.  That the purposes of election might stand.  God chooses whom to save, that none might boast of their own merit.

Comment: Paul's own salvation was a powerful lesson to Paul of the way of salvation by grace alone through faith in Christ alone.

Comment: How can Judas serve as a reminder to make our calling and election sure if we have nothing to do with our (effectual) calling and election?

Comment: @MikeBorden - "Make your calling and election sure" 2 Peter 1:10.  It is true we have nothing to do with our election or calling, but our calling calls us to be conformed to the image of his son.  Our election has a knock on effect on our lives.  "Examine yourselves to see if you be in the faith." (2 Cor 13:5)  It is not enough to claim to be elect, the marks of election should be evident in our lives, if they are not we should take corrective action as per 2 Peter 1 and 2 Corinthians 13.

Comment: If the marks of election are not evident it could be because that one has not been elected. If that is the case there is no corrective action to take.

Comment: God has not only chosen _who_ will be saved, but _how_ they will be saved.  If a person uses the means of salvation then he will be saved.  And then he will realize he was elect/called/chosen. A person cannot know he is not elect, so everyone should use the means of faith and repentance.

Comment: "Every true Christian has been called and chosen" sounds a little like a "[true Scotsman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_true_Scotsman)" and might be at risk of being a circular definition.

Comment: Of course it is, but it was being called into doubt by the one asking the question.. so maybe not as circular as you and I think.  I'm just trying to make my answer suit the question. Perhaps I should say "effectually called".

Comment: @Henry - Does the postscript anchoring my answer in scripture help stop it being a true scotsman definition answer in your opinion?

Answer (score 2):

Context is so important and all of Matthew 21 through 22:14 should be read.  The triumphal entry has taken place, the people are extolling the King and the religious leaders are looking to trap Him and ultimately kill him.

Jesus begins to describe the kingdom and the religious leaders in parables and the culmination of chapter 21 is:

> And when the chief priests and Pharisees had heard his parables, they
> perceived that he spake of them. But when they sought to lay hands on
> him, they feared the multitude, because they took him for a prophet. -
> Mat. 21:45-46

The next chapter is a continuation of Jesus' rebuke of the chief priests and the Pharisees which contains the verse in question:

> Indeed many are called but few are chosen - Matthew 22:14

Many are "invited" but few are "selected".

This is part of a kingdom parable in which the original guests invited beforehand (Israel) to a wedding feast not only declined to attend but murdered the servants (prophets) sent to gather them.  (In a similar parable they also murdered the King's son.)  The King sent his armies to destroy those guests and their city (Jerusalem) and then sent other servants (apostles) to the highways and byways to invite anyone and everyone (Jew and Gentile), **both good and bad**, to populate his wedding feast.

One was found in the wedding without appropriate attire:  How could this be?

It is to be assumed that the servants who went out and at the 11th hour furnished the wedding with guests from the highways also provided them proper wedding garments.  This one who was not properly attired therefore represents one who did not properly respond to the invitation, was not properly clothed and, within the greater context, must be one of the original invitees who first declined to attend or a proselyte thereof.

We must remember that Jesus is speaking this parable against the Chief Priests, the Pharisees, and all who stand opposed.

Many are called but those who refuse to respond to the call are rejected as improperly clothed.  They may find their way to the feast but they arrive clothed in their own righteousness (filthy rags) and, bereft of the righteousness of Christ in which true guests must be clothed, they are cast out.  Those who have responded to the call, "repent and believe", and are clothed properly (by the King) are those who were foreknown to so respond from the foundation of the world and are therefore chosen ([or elect](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Peter%201%3A1-2&version=KJV)) according to the foreknowledge of God.

It is not that God effectually calls some and effectually reprobates others without any possibility of human choice but rather that the call is genuine and the choice of response is foreknown.  Judas betrayal did not take Jesus by surprise.  Therefore Jesus said, "The kingdom of God is at hand."  And in another place it is written, "Multitudes, multitudes in the valley of decision." And again, "O Jerusalem, Jerusalem, thou that killest the prophets, and stonest them which are sent unto thee, how often would I have gathered thy children together, even as a hen gathereth her chickens under her wings, and **ye would not**!".

He does not say that they could not.  He says that they would not.  *[θελω (thelo)](https://www.abarim-publications.com/DictionaryG/th/th-e-l-om.html)*:  They actively did not want to.

The Kingdom of heaven, in it's parabolic form, is not to be equated with the company of those who are saved until the consummation and the judgement:

> Again, the kingdom of heaven is like unto a net, that was cast into the sea, and gathered of every kind: Which, when it was full, they drew to shore, and sat down, and gathered the good into vessels, but cast the bad away. So shall it be at the end of the world: the angels shall come forth, and sever the wicked from among the just, 
> And shall cast them into the furnace of fire: there shall be wailing and gnashing of teeth. - Matthew 13:47-50

The Kingdom of heaven is at hand.  The King has come.  He has been rejected and killed by the original invitees.  They have no wedding attire and are no longer welcome unless they say, "Blessed is He who comes in the name of the Lord".  Their beforehand invitation has been revoked but [they are not utterly cast aside](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans%2011%3A1-5&version=KJV) so long as they repent and believe.  The Gospel of the kingdom has gone out into the highways and byways and as many as believe have been called/invited and shall be clothed:  Both the believing remnant of Israel and the believing Gentiles who are grafted in.

> And I heard as it were the voice of a great multitude, and as the voice of many waters, and as the voice of mighty thunderings, saying, Alleluia: for the Lord God omnipotent reigneth. Let us be glad and rejoice, and give honour to him: for the marriage of the Lamb is come, and his wife hath made herself ready. And to her was granted that she should be arrayed in fine linen, clean and white: for the fine linen is the righteousness of saints. And he saith unto me, Write, Blessed are they which are called unto the marriage supper of the Lamb. And he saith unto me, These are the true sayings of God. - Revelation 19:6-9

Comment: It also means you cannot come to God unless it is granted you by him.

Comment: @SoFewAgainstSoMany It has been granted. The son of man has been lifted up just as Moses lifted up the serpent in the desert.  If someone refuses to repent and believe it is not because God has withheld the ability from them.

Comment: Do you agree it is very cruel of God to create people who he knew beforehand were not going to repent?

Comment: @AndrewShanks Not at all, really.  A choice is not less of a choice just because God's foreknowledge is perfect.  He foreknew Adam would sin and all humanity is in Adam.  It seems much more cruel to command everyone to repent and believe all the while withholding the ability to do so from most and only granting it to a few.  I can't make sense of the Scriptures that way.

Comment: So you believe God is sovereign except in the area of human decision making?  You believe that that area of the universe is outside of his control?

Comment: @AndrewShanks I believe God created Adam with a faculty of choice rather than that God sovereignly made Adam disobey.   Divine sovereignty does not negate human volition.  In fact His sovereignty is magnified in that we have volition and He still works all things together for the good of those who love Him.  He is not willing that any should perish yet many do and will.  How to reconcile this statement of God's desire and the fact that few find salvation with a sovereignty that absolutely controls human choice in that area?

Comment: @Andrew Shanks Is it cruel for all to receive life and breath, even though none are worthy of His holy presence or His generosity (Rom 3:10), yet He chooses to show mercy and compassion only to some (Rom 9:14-23?.  Does not the potter have the sovereign right over to clay to make or destroy as He chooses?

Comment: @AFL - some think that if God has predestined everything then man has no choice, if God has predestined man to eternal punishment then why does he blame us at all?  They prefer to fall back on the view that God only knows beforehand our choices, but our salvation is not ultimately his gift to his chosen few, but our choice of a general offer to all.  And they suppose this absolves God of all guilt.  My point is this hypothetical position does not absolve God of all guilt. It makes his guilt worse.. he sees ahead our choices but does not do anything about it (if you believe His knowing only).

Comment: @Afl - I hold God predestined his elect few to salvation, but those who reject the Gospel offer are guilty of their rejection, they cannot blame God. God is sovereign in everything, man is responsible for his choices.  If we cannot resolve the seeming paradox then we simply hold on to all scripture truth.. scripture should be more vital to us than our logic. Of course I do not believe God is cruel in his election.  If there were no election no one would be saved.

Comment: @AndrewShanks So man can reject the gospel but cannot accept it?  The only choice man has is a negative choice?

Comment: @MikeBorden - man has lost the desire to find God.  Only God can give him back that desire.  Man has lost the desire because he loves his sin.

Comment: @AndrewShanks And God could give that desire to everyone but He does not and yet says He wants everyone to come to repentance.  He's not willing that any should perish but He withholds the ability to repent from most, thereby insuring that they perish.  Choiceless reprobation is a terrible doctrine.   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WGIwHhVL68Y

Comment: @MikeBorden - Nobody knows if they are reprobate.  The people of Ninevah were not even promised forgiveness upon repentance, but they reasoned.."Who knows? If we repent maybe God will relent." They repented and God relented.  Now the reprobate have it preached to them the Gospel, if you repent, God will forgive... yet they do not care. They do not care if they are reprobate, they do not care for anything, except sin and wickedness.  Everything that happens is in God's Eternal Decree.  When a man robs a bank, or tortures a child, it is in God's Eternal Decree.. but God is love.. it cannot be

Comment: @MikeBorden cannot be any fault of God, nor can any man who does such things say "It was in God's plan, therefore I am guiltless."  Evil is man's responsibility, man will be punished for his choices, God is guiltless.. what we cannot understand we submit to what we know about the character and goodness of God as shown in Holy Scripture.  Your problem, imo, if you don't mind too much me saying, is you elevate your logic above God's word.  We are totally depraved, and that includes our logical faculties.  Where we cannot make logical sense of God's word, we renounce logic and hold to the Word.

Comment: @AndrewShanks Were it not for the Word and merely going by the circumstances of my salvation I would likely be a Calvinist.  "Who knows? If we repent maybe God will relent."  Exactly.  They chose to repent because they were given the opportunity.  God saw and responded to their choice.  There is nothing in Jonah that speaks of Calvinism.  God foreknew they would repent and Jonah knew that if they did God would relent but nothing in the book indicates God causing the repentance other than sending Jonah to preach a convicting message.  I cannot hold to the Word and disallow human choice.

Comment: @AndrewShanks In Athens, Paul says that we are each born where and when so that we may seek the Lord and perhaps find Him.  Holding to the Word often involves hanging on to truths that are in tension by our understanding.  God's sovereignty and man's free agency is one example.  Both are clearly taught in Scripture and it is not right to abandon one and cling to the other no matter how difficult, IMO.  Deuteronomy 30, esp. v.19 makes no sense if man does not have choice.  Neither does John  1:11-12 which indicates active acceptance or rejection, not passive.

Comment: @MikeBorden - you say _Nothing in the book _ [of Jonah] _ indicates God causing the repentance other than sending Jonah..etc_  True, but though the book does not, The Book is clear.. repentance is given by God as all good gifts are from above. What do we have that we have not received? God gives repentance, as he does also faith. The root cause is election, and the reason he elects some but not others is his love towards his elect.  In love he predestined us.  The reason we choose him is because, in his love, he first chose us..even tho there was nothing distinctive in us from others. Jacob I

Comment: @MikeBorden - Jacob I loved, Esau (with respect to election) I hated. The blame for Esau's rejection is entirely Esau's, the praise for Jacob's salvation belongs exclusively to God. All who repent only do so because God gives them the gift, and they only desire the gift because God gives them the desire. Then has God also to the Gentiles granted repentance unto life (Acts 11:18).    But those die outside of Christ, without salvation, it is exactly what God ordained, they stumble at the word, being disobedient, which is also what they were destined for (1 Peter 1:8, and John 10:26).

Comment: @MikeBorden - God did not give the ability to repent to all, Acts 11:18 does not say that, it says he gave repentance to those, and only those, who had repented.  When genesis says Adam knew Eve it is speaking of intimacy that springs from love.  And when Romans 8:29  speaks of foreknowledge it is refering to _persons_, not the actions of persons, it means God foreloved he _loved them beforehand_; the same as in Eph 1:4-5 _In love he predestined us.._ etc.  You say _it makes no sense if man does not have choice_. But who said man does not have a choice? Not me.. Joshua 24:15.

Answer (score 2):

There are initial questions that must be cleared up at the outset; four in total:

**Called by whom, for what?**

**Chosen by whom, to what?**

Jesus was speaking from verse 1 in Matthew 22 through to the verse in question and right on to the end of that chapter to a group of religious people who were trying to trap him with their questions. Start reading from chapter 21 verse 45.

Context for the verse in question is a parable Jesus gave about who shall enter into the kingdom of heaven, and who shall not. He is speaking to Jewish people. The parable is about a marriage being prepared for the son of a king. Many are invited to attend - twice, and twice they despise the invitation, then some killed the servants who kept inviting them. Upon hearing this, the king sent armies to destroy those murderers and their city.

The king then declares those initially invited were not worthy, and for fresh invitations to be issues to anyone the servants met in the highways - "good and bad". They readily accepted and (as the custom back then) were issued with wedding garments. But a man sneaked in, uninvited, as proven by the fact that he was not wearing the wedding garment of the invited guests. The king asked for an explanation, but the man was speechless. The king instructed his servants:

> "Bind him hand and foot, and take him away, and cast him into outer
> darkness; there shall be weeping and gnashing of teeth. For many are
> called, but few are chosen." Matt. 22:13-14 K.J.V.

It could not be any more obvious what Jesus was saying about who are called, but why few are chosen. God invites into his heavenly kingdom those who can be at "the marriage supper of the Lamb" (Revelation 19:7) - but many of them despise this unspeakable privilege. However, others who are so often looked down upon rejoice, get cleaned up with new garments to identify them, and attend this wedding of the King's Son. But woe betide any who try to sneak in without the King's approval! He identifies those chosen to be in the presence of himself and his Son with his garments - I would call them the "garments of salvation", as here:

> "And their seed shall be known among the Gentiles, and their
> offspring among the people: all that see them shall acknowledge them,
> that they are the seed which the Lord hath blessed. I will greatly
> rejoice in the Lord, my soul shall be joyful in my God; for he hath
> clothed me with the garments of salvation, he hath covered me with the
> robe of righteousness, as a bridegroom decketh himself with
> ornaments, and as a bride adorneth herself with her jewels. Isaiah
> 61:9-10 K.J.V.

All four of those initial questions have been answered via Jesus' parable and what the prophet Isaiah foretold.

Now progress can be made to see if this claim is sound or not: **This [sic]* ***two verses show that even for Christians they cannot come to God unless God already called them and no matter what they do, if God hasn't called them they won't be saved***.*

The parable was addressed to Jewish people. The meaning is clear in light of those who hated the Servant of the Lord coming to them, put him to death, then had many of their people, their temple, indeed, much of their nation destroyed by Roman armies in A.D.70. But those who believed Jesus and heeded his parables and his warnings as to how to escape with their lives grew into those for whom their Lord had died, realising (with hindsight) that God had called and chosen them to be in his heavenly Kingdom. He has identified them, and they will be at the marriage supper of the Lamb.

It only remains to be said that John 3:27 fits in perfectly with all of that, for the speaker (John the Baptist) went on to say:

> "Ye yourselves bear me witness, that I said, I am not the Christ, but
> that I am sent before him. He that hath the bride is the bridegroom,
> but the friend of the bridegroom, which standeth and heareth him,
> rejoiceth greatly because of the bridegroom's voice. He must increase,
> but I must decrease." John 3:28-30 K.J.V.

He who was sent to prepare the Jewish people for the coming of the King's Son was put to a horrible death. In conclusion, see how John's closing words in chapter 3 show plainly what determines if a person is called and chosen to be in the heavenly Kingdom of God:

> "He that believeth on the Son hath everlasting life: and he that
> believeth not the Son shall not see life; but the wrath of God abideth
> on him." John 3:36

**Answer** to ***this*** question, "Can ***a person*** be called but not chosen?" Absolutely, as Jesus' parable shows. **Underlying answer:** "Such a one who treats the calling with contempt never was a Christian in the first place, and never will be. But those who receive the calling to the wedding feast of the Lamb and are identified by God with his garments of righteousness, ***will become Christians*** and undeservedly so."

Comment: I knew you before you were formed in yout mother's womb means that God already has the list of saved people just waiting for it to be fulfilled

Answer (score 1):

The answers so far seem rather overly long and complicated.

The simple answer is: "*Yes, Christians *can* be called but not chosen*", and needs little explanation.

Jesus said that Christians can become unworthy of their calling:

> **Luke 21**:
> **<sup>34</sup>** And take heed to yourselves, lest at any time your hearts be overcharged with surfeiting, and drunkenness, and cares of this life, and so that day come upon you unawares.
> **<sup>35</sup>** For as a snare shall it come on all them that dwell on the face of the whole earth.
> **<sup>36</sup>** Watch ye therefore, and pray always, that ye may be accounted worthy to escape all these things that shall come to pass, and to stand before the Son of man.

Paul repeated the message:

> **2 Thessalonians 1:11**:
> Wherefore also we pray always for you, that our God would count you worthy of this calling, and fulfil all the good pleasure of his goodness, and the work of faith with power:

And Jesus's message to the Laodiceans shows that whole churches can be rejected:

> **Revelation 3**:
> **<sup>15</sup>** I know thy works, that thou art neither cold nor hot: I would thou wert cold or hot.
> **<sup>16</sup>** So then because thou art lukewarm, and neither cold nor hot, I will spue thee out of my mouth.